# create view from the value of the item on a spinner

Tags: java, android

I 'm a beginner in stackoverflow
this is what I want to do this is create views from the value in the spinner as an example if the list in the spinner is 2 so if I select 2 it will display two editText

In fact I have a spinner which contains numbers 1 to 5 and what I would like to do is that if I select the number two for example it makes two editText

Comment: very shallow question, Please provide me as much details as possible.

Comment: I have spinner which contains as arrayAdapter an integer which contains digits 1 to 4. is what I would like to do is that if I select the two number for example, it displays two editText and if it is 3 three editText and so on